# Googleads AD Manger Unable to Open Database File in Flask Application Running on EKS with ArgoCD and Helm

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-eks, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am running a Flask application on EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) and managing it with ArgoCD and Helm. The application is using Google Ad Manager API. The error message is as follows:

```
  File "/flask/app/forecast/forecast_route.py", line 20, in forecast
    forecasted_results = forecast_impression(criteria)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/flask/app/forecast/services/forecast_service.py", line 13, in forecast_impression
    forecasted_impression = ad_service.ad_forecast_impression(criteria_result)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/flask/app/forecast/services/ad_manager_service.py", line 84, in ad_forecast_impression
    targeting = self.getTargeting(criteria)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/flask/app/forecast/services/ad_manager_service.py", line 239, in getTargeting
    GetService('InventoryService')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleads/ad_manager.py", line 381, in GetService
    service = googleads.common.GetServiceClassForLibrary()(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 762, in __init__
    transport = _ZeepProxyTransport(timeout, proxy_config, cache)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 510, in __init__
    cache = zeep.cache.SqliteCache()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/cache.py", line 121, in __init__
    with self.db_connection() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/cache.py", line 134, in db_connection
    connection = sqlite3.connect(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
Exception ignored in: <function Transport.__del__ at 0x7ff214d17060>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 159, in __del__
    if self._close_session:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_ZeepProxyTransport' object has no attribute '_close_session'
```

I have tested the application in local environment and it works.